# Recurring events show up in UTC time 

Tags: android, icalendar

I am working on sending Meeting Invites from my Android app.

Here is the generated [iCal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar).

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:Test//Outlook//EN
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:GMT-6 standard time
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:16010101T020000
TZOFFSETFROM:-0500
TZOFFSETTO:-0600
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=11;BYDAY=1SU
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
DTSTART:16010101T020000
TZOFFSETFROM:-0600
TZOFFSETTO:-0500
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=3;BYDAY=2SU
END:DAYLIGHT
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
DESCRIPTION;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:this is a recurring event
SUMMARY;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:RecurringEvent
DTSTART:20100618T010000Z
DTEND:20100618T020000Z
DTSTAMP:20100618T004215Z
LOCATION;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:Someplace
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=TRUE;CN=Sagar:MAILTO:sagar.hatekar@gmail.com
RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=TH
SEQUENCE:0
UID:040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E008000000000000000000000000000000000000000
010000000251D69F4288A137B1891F782A1836CCB
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

This event starts at 8 p.m. [CDT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_Central_Time_Zone) and ends at 9 p.m. CDT. However, when this meeting request is received in Outlook, the "when" section reads as "Thursday, June 17, 2010 01:00AM-02:00AM GMT-5 standard time".

EDIT:
I am sending a meeting request from using Android 2.x (Eclair) source code for email and calendar.

Comment: What does this have to do with android? are you syncing your outlook calendar to google calendar with a 3rd party app?

Comment: I was implementing Meeting Invite functionality on Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself!

For recurring events, I append the TZID ('defined' in VTIMEZONE) to the DTSTART and DTEND and send the local times.

It works!

Even Outlook does it the same way.